# ORACLE - SELECT with an aggregate function and MONTHS_BETWEEN

Tags: oracle, select, where-clause

I have a difficulty with displaying the proper results. My formula is supposed to display those ENAME's of people who have Sum of SAL + COMM > 1200 and have worked at least 40 years. I think it's because of an NVL function inside. Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

```
SELECT ENAME 
FROM SCOTT.EMP 
WHERE NVL(SUM(SAL), 0) + NVL(SUM(COMM), 0) > 1200 
AND MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, HIREDATE) > 480
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `SUM` (as a function):

```
where nvl(sal, 0) + nvl(comm, 0) > 1200
  and hiredate < add_months(trunc(sysdate), -40 * 12)
```

Comment: Thank you, you saved me, however if i had a problem that complex that i needed to use those SUM functions, how would you recomend doing that?

Comment: You're welcome. I wouldn't recommend anything as I don't know what you really have. It just depends ... *maybe* it would be something like `sum(nvl(sal, 0) + nvl(comm, 0)) > 1200` but then again, maybe it wouldn't. Can't tell.